# Bulk update post slugs through database

Tags: posts, permalinks, slug, sql

Is there a way to bulk update permalinks through the database? cause I have like 20k posts and all I want to do is add a prefix to the permalink. I could just manually update but that's too tiresome for 20k posts.

For example if post url is `http://example.com/post-1`
I want to change it to `http://example/pre-post-1`

Comment: Permalinks are **not** stored in database. Do you maybe mean post slugs?

Comment: If you're unsure, please post a specific example of what you need to do. I made the mistake of assuming this was a question about a database search and replace for hard coded links and flagged it as off topic. I should have asked first, so sorry if I was mistaken!

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum, I think you should be able to remove the close vote, just click it again and it should give you the option.

Comment: @G. M Yes I mean post slugs

Comment: @Ruriko Please always add additional info as [edit] to your question.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728292/bulk-rewrite-post-slugs-based-on-custom-field-value-in-wordpress

You can probably make a plugin for this.

Comment: Pretty trivial with a SQL [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) but I am hesitant to recommend it without knowing more details about the why and the what of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query, remembering to change out `your_posts_table` with the proper name in your database. Using `CONCAT`, you can add any number of strings, just pass `post_name` to add your changes before/after.

```
update your_posts_table
set post_name = CONCAT('pre-', post_name)
```

- More info on [MySQL CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- **Note:** Use a `WHERE` clause if you only want to update specific posts.